# Sync a file across multiple devices

Tags: unity, synchronization

How can a file be synced across multiple devices? I am able to store the data locally using binary serialization, but the user should have the ability to access it on any device at any time.

Is this done automatically by the operating system? If the user logs into an Android phone using a Google account, would local data created by the application appear on every device that Google account is logged into or would I need to implement this functionality myself?

I have considered using a remote database, but I am not so sure that is the best option. My target platforms are Windows Universal, Android, and iOS.

The closest topic I found when I researched this is "Remote Settings" and "binary serialization", but neither help in my case.

Comment: This is very much a manual process. Most ways this is done involves a server you control or a 3rd party service. These options are not free though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered saving/loading data into/from XML (or Json) ? It can easily be read from a remote source as TextAsset and parsed.

This Unify snippet is a good starting point to save/load your data as an XML text file (either from/into the Resources/ folder, from the persistent DataPath or from a remote source using www.text): [Saving and Loading Data: XmlSerializer](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer)

Then for your remote server, i guess the Firebase Storage free plan should be more than enough, they provide a great Unity documentation for [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/upload-files).